# Application file on Macbook will not show up in Finder and is not able to be deleted from computer

Tags: macbook-pro, applications, storage, macos

One file on my computer "Total War: Rome II Emperor edition" is not able to be deleted from the system. When trying to delete it from the manage storage window panel, there is no way to do it. When I try to click the button "show in finder" nothing shows up. Also when looking for the file on my computer it is nowhere to be found. I had downloaded this application from Steam. Attached are photos of what I have tried to do.

[image]

Comment: It’s not clear what window gives you show in finder but can you use Spotlight to show that file and get info on it? Looks like steam has locked it so if you like that answer you can accept it rather than clarifying the post.

Answer (score 2):

The general method of properly uninstalling games downloaded via steam:

Go to your games **Library** on the Steam app. Next, use the sidebar to select the game that you want to uninstall. Click on the gear-shaped settings button > manage > uninstall.

Refer to the attached screenshot for a detailed view:

[image]